# Data Service in Talend open studio for Data integration

Tags: talend, data-integration, talend-mdm

I am trying to fetch streaming data from one of my machine to another, I have used Talend open studio for data integration in case of batch data,I guess I can achieve the same for streaming using data service but I don't know how to create data service in Talend Data integration tool or is it even provide the option for creating a service.

Comment: The question is unclear, could you please elaborate on it and provide more information by answering the question: What's the data source? What software versions do you use? What's your goal? What solutions you have already tried? I believe I'll be able to help if I have enough details.

Comment: @AntonGoncharov I am currently using Talend open studio for Data Integration (free version) my use case to get log file from one of my linux system to another system. There are 2 type of file, one is batch file(processing will be done once a day ) and another is stream data file (real time processing). I want to achieve the 2nd part, How to achieve this using any software provided by Talend.

Comment: are you watching for new files in a folder, or do you need to stream a single log file contents as it gets new lines appended? Would be helpful if you updated your question above with all these details so that page visitors could see all the information in the original question.